# LPSolve - specify constant coefficients

Tags: linear-programming, lpsolve

I'm using LPSolve IDE to solve a LP problem. I have to test the model against about 10 or 20 sets of different parameters and compare them.

Is there any way for me to keep the general model, but to specify the constants as I wish? For example, if I have the following constraint:

`A >= [c]*B`

I want to test how the model behaves when `[c] = 10`, `[c] = 20`, and so on. For now, I'm simply preparing different .lp files via search&replace, but:

a) it doesn't seem too efficient

b) at some point, I need to consider the constraint of the form `A >= B/[c] // =(1/[c]*B)`. It seems, however, that LPSolve doesn't recogize the division operator. Is specifying `1/[c]` directly each time the only option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not completely clear what format you use with lp_solve. With the cplex lp format for example, there is no better way: you cannot use division for the coefficient (or even multiplication for that matter) and there is no function to 'include' another file or introduce a symbolic names for a parameter. It is a very simple language, and not suitable for any complex task.

There are several solutions for your problem; it depends if you are interested in something fast to implement, or 'clean', reusable and with a short runtime (of course this is a compromise).

1. You have the possibility to generate your lp files from another language, e.g. python, bash, etc. This is a 'quick and dirty' solution: very slow at runtime, but probably the faster to implement.
2. As every lp solver I know, lp_solve comes with several modelling interfaces: you can for example use the [GNU mp format](http://plato.asu.edu/gnu_mp.pdf) instead of the current one. It recognizes multiplication, divisions, conditionals, etc. (everything you are looking for, see the section 3.1 'numeric expressions')
3. Finally, you have the possibility to use directly the lp_solve interface from another programming language (e.g. C) which will be the most flexible option, but it may require a little bit more work.

See the [lp_solve documentation](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/) for more details on the supported input formats and the API reference.